# Discord.py wait_for()

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I have an `on_message()` event, but I want to turn in into a command, the problem is that when I change it, the `wait_for()` function doesn't work.
Is there any equivalent of `wait_for()` in `@client.command()`?

My code:

````
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    channel = message.author
    def check(m):
        return m.channel == message.channel and m.author != client.user

    if message.content.startswith("!order"):
        await channel.send("in game name")
        in_game_name = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

        await channel.send("in game ID")
        in_game_ID = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    else:
        await client.process_commands(message)```
````

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"?  What does happen?  `wait_for` doesn't have anything to do with commands, it should work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First things first, that video shows your bot's login token. This is meant to be a secret key known only to you, and I would recommend **taking down that video and changing the key [here](https://discord.com/developers/applications/) *immediately*! People with access to that key can take control your bot.**

In the video that you sent in reply to a comment from Patrick Haugh, you used the discord.ext.commands framework, so that is what I will be using here.
The `ctx` parameter in your `order` command is a [Context](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Context), and instead of calling `send()` on the channel like you do in your video, you should call it on the context like this: `ctx.send('foo')`.

Also, on lines 18 and 21, you use

```
await client.wait_for('ctx', check=check)
```

As explained [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for), the events you can use as the first argument of `Client.wait_for()` are given in the [event reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=wait_for#discord-api-events), just remove the `on_` prefix. In your case, I think you want `on_message`, so it would look something like this:

```
@client.command()
async def order(self, ctx: commands.Context):
    def check(message: discord.Message):
        return message.channel == ctx.channel and message.author != ctx.me

    await ctx.send('foo')
    foo = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    await ctx.send('bar')
    bar = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
```

In this case, `foo` and `bar` are instances of [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#message), and you can get the content of those messages using `foo.content` and `bar.content` respectively.