# I'm trying to create a discord bot that will ping a role, with a sponsor and message, but It includes the entire message, what can I do?

Tags: python, split, discord.py, message

So I'm trying to make a discord bot with python, and I would like it to ping a certain role, adding parts of your message into specific places. Such as: @role, Sponsor: @person, Message: message.

This is my code;

```
      if message.content[11:] != message.content:
          if message.content[10:] != "@Johnny Wobble#1085":
            print("confirmed stage 2")
            responses = [
                   "<@&820375570307088404>",
                   f"Sponser: {message.content[10:]}",
                   f"Message: {message.content[11:]}",
            ]
            await message.delete()
            await message.channel.send(responses)
      else:
            print("confirmed stage 3")
            await client.send_message(message.channel, f"Ah, I see you {message.author.mention}, trying to turn me agai"
            f"nst my master eh? Well I say no! I cannot believe you would think that I would ever do that to the all-po"
            f"werful Max (Gordon)!")
```

I tried this code but it just ends up repeating the entire message.

For example: -gw @person pls work

Then it returns '@role' 'Sponsor: @person pls work' 'Message: @person pls work'

Do I have some problems in my code?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using the commands extension rather than using an `on_message` event. If you're already doing that and I misread your question, please view the next section of this answer.

```py
from discord.ext import commands # unsure if importing is necessary, usually used for cogs

# ...
# set up code with client and on_ready and what not
# ...

@client.command()
async def sponsor(ctx, role: discord.Role, *, message="Sponsor message"):
    # get the role if given is valid, message is 'Sponsor message' if nothing is given
    await ctx.send(f"""
{role.mention}
Sponsor: {ctx.author.mention}
Message: {message}
""")

# role.mention : mentions the given role
# sponsor : mentions the person who originally invoked the command
```

[image: Above code working]

---

Assuming that you are using the commands extension already, you may use [`client.wait_for`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for). This is used if you want your bot to listen to the channel for a specific message under a command.

```py
@client.command()
async def sponsor(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel
    
    await ctx.send("Send the thing:")
    response = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

# Two different ways you may want to split your message:
# --- The first way to do it would be to split at a certain keyword, for example 'msg' --- #
    role, message = response.content.split('msg:', 1)

# --- The other way would be to split it from the first space --- #
    role, message = response.content.split(' ', 1)

# sending the message here
    await ctx.send(f"""
{role}
Sponsor: {ctx.author.mention}
Message: {message}
""")
```

Working Method 1

[image: Working Method 1]

Working Method 2

[image: Working Method 2]

---

References:

- [SO: Split a string only by first space in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30636248/split-a-string-only-by-first-space-in-python)
- [SO: Discord.py-rewrite wait_for() how do i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52571844/discord-py-rewrite-wait-for-how-do-i-use)
- [SO: Discord.py wait_for()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61939943/discord-py-wait-for)
- [Docs: `wait_for(event, *, check=None, timeout=None)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=client%20wait_for#discord.Client.wait_for)

Comment: I tried using your code, but when I try running the bot, it says there 'Client' has no attribute 'command'. When I tried searching up what I could do to fix this error, it said I should use "bot.command" instead, but when I use bot.command, nothing happens.

Comment: Since you have an `on_message` event, you'll need to process it, otherwise commands won't work. [Have a look here for an answer to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331419/14420546)

Comment: Also, I just noticed you used `client.send_message` in your code, so you may need to change this to `bot.send_message` or `message.channel.send("")` instead.